# Trying to simulate the bending of a right angled pipe in solidworks

Tags: pipelines, solidworks

I have created a bent right angled tube in solid works.

It has a constant inner diameter of 1" and thickness of 1/8".

The tube is comprised of a straight portion 1 ft in length, followed by a 90 deg bend with a 10 cm radius of curvature, then another straight portion 10 cm in length. I apologize for mixed units, I am just trying to make a proof of concept at this time so I will change the dimensions later.

I've fixed the first flat face of 1 ft section at the top, and I have set the material to natural rubber for now but I would probably want it to be neoprene or polyethylene in the finished product.

I want to deflect the second shorter straight portion by an angle of 45 deg in the plane and measure the deflection in the curved section. **Is there a way that I can directly apply a deflection (angular preferably) to the end of the 10 cm length tube and measure the change of the arc in the curved section?** I have had to apply a load, but I don't really have any idea of knowing what that should be to correspond to the desired deflection.

Below is an image using alloy steel because the simulation kept failing if I applied a load to rubber?

[image]